# Getting Invalid object name 'diagnostics482413' error on deletion of any node in content tree

Tags: site-configuration

I am using Sitecore 8.1, while i am trying to delete any node in content tree then getting `Invalid object name 'diagnostics482413' error`. This error is getting on prod cms server, while the dev and qa is working fine. After some analysis i found below things,

i) Table name as `diagnostics482413` is missing in prod master database but it is present in our DEV and QA master database.

ii) There is one config patch file `Sitecore.Support.Diagnostics.482413.config`, this is present on all instances.

So can any one explain me what exactly the issue is and for which purpose this `Sitecore.Support.Diagnostics.482413.config` patch file is used?

Comment: Is the supporting DLL present on all instances as well?

Comment: Yes Mark, all the DLL are present on each instace. Means they are replica of each other.

Comment: Seems like you will need to create the missing parts on prod db to fix it. If you want to know what it does, contact Sitecore Support (or search your support history). Support will probably provided you with the patch..

Comment: Sure Gatogordo will do that

Comment: @Sam - Can you please check the Templates section and confirm if the template that was used to create the specific item is not updated/deleted/missing as part of some sitecore package update or something similar while moving your items to the different environments.

Comment: Please check if there was any SQL script provided with this patch which was supposed to run on your master database. The fix can be your project specific. You can Check with Sitecore support as well

Comment: @Alok as I mentioned one table  is missing from master database of prod instance i.e "diagnostic 482414" but it is present on dev and qa instances. So definitely that this "diagnostics482413" is a support package and it has ran on one instance , and while creating prod instace someone had not run this package and just copy paste the files ,so the database changes are not updated. Now the problem is i am trying to find out this package on net but not found any single blog on this. So how can I get that package and any information which give me idea that for which purpose this package is used​ ?

Comment: Table name is looking like a test table. I am suspecting that to understand some other issue in the product and to get logging information sitecore support might have provided you with a diagnostic DLL and script which your team might have tested on dev and qa. But somehow by mistake this patch is propagated tk your prod. So you should check with the team for which sitecore support ticket this patch was provided.